# DNN Custom Email - how to include core hyperlinks

Tags: dotnetnuke-9, dotnetnuke

I am trying to send an email and in the footer I need to include the `[Unsubscribe]`, `[SITEURL]`, `[PORTALNAME]` hyperlinks that come with some default DNN emails.

What I have done so far:

1. I created a `test.resx` file under my custom module's `App_LocalResources` folder. In this file I have an entry `MY_EMAIL_TEST.Text`
   In this entry my `html` looks like:

   ```
                       <!-- // Begin Module: Standard Preheader \ -->
                       <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" align="center" >

                           <tr>
                               <td align="center">
                                   <p>Copyright 2013 <a href="[SITEURL]">[PORTALNAME]</a> All rights reserved.</p>
                                   <p>If you wish to no longer receive emails in the future, please <a href="[UNSUBSCRIBEURL]">unsubscribe</a> here.</p>
                               </td>
                           </tr>
                       </table>
                       <!-- // End Module: Standard Preheader \ -->
                   </td>
               </tr>
           </table>
           <!-- // End Template footer \\ -->
   ```

   which is basically some HTML that I have copy/pasted from the EMAIL_MESSAGING_DISPATCH_BODY.Text which is in the GlobalResources.
2. I get the string from this file like this:

   ```
   Dim body = Localization.GetSystemMessage(GetPortalSettings, "MY_EMAIL_TEST.Text", "DesktopModules/FinBidders/App_LocalResources/test.resx")
   ```
3. I send the email:

   ```
    DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.Mail.SendMail(Host.HostEmail, 
    oUserInfoReceiver.Email, 
    "", "", 
    DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.MailPriority.Normal, 
    "my subject",                                                 
    DotNetNuke.Services.Mail.MailFormat.Html, 
    Text.Encoding.Default, 
    body, 
    "", Entities.Host.Host.SMTPServer, 
    Entities.Host.Host.SMTPAuthentication,
    Entities.Host.Host.SMTPUsername, Entities.Host.Host.SMTPPassword,False)
   ```

Notice that I specify that the format is `MailFormat.Html`.

Now the email I receive has **NO hyperlinks** to unsubscribe, portalname or siteurl. They appear as text!

Email content after it is received:

> Copyright 2018 [[SITEURL]][PORTALNAME] All rights reserved.
>
> If you wish to no longer receive emails in the future, please > [[UNSUBSCRIBEURL]]unsubscribe here.

**How can these links be formatted with the proper hyperlink?**

Comment: I don't think `DotNetNuke.Services.Mail` replaces tokes. It just sends the mails. You have to replace them yourself.

Comment: @VDWWD Thanks. It does make some replacements such as User:DisplayName, but it's a different game when using the scheduler. Therefore, I am replacing them myself.